# Autowrite VIM buffers after <alt-tab>

Tags: vim, macvim

How can I configure vim to *autowrite* buffers after switching with <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to another application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want:

```
autocmd FocusLost * :wall
```

In your .vimrc

I just tried it and it seems to work.

Comment: I think this can only work in gvim? Because if you run vim in a terminal, it knows nothing about windows or focus.

Comment: Actually the vim doc says: "Only for the GUI and a few console versions were this can be detected" although I've got no idea what those would be....

Comment: Thx for your answer. It's working for gvim but not for vim in a linux shell.

Comment: Hi 1passenger, I'm pretty sure this would be impossible for vim in a linux shell for the reasons above.  (Unless you wrote some kind of C code to interface to xwindows that is but I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Check out Steve Losh's vim-vitality plugin. It can help in certain situations. https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim